# Can I have two urls.py with different names?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-cms

In Django, is it possible to have two different files with url patterns, neither of which is called `urls.py` ? Or does Django rely on there being only one set of url patterns per Django app, and that it must be called `urls.py` ?

I'm using Django CMS and I want to split an app across two apphooks and two menus. So I've tried splitting `urls.py` into `pub_urls.py` and `train_urls.py` but I appear to have broken things by doing that, despite the `cms_app.py` naming the correct urls - eg:

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from resources.menu import TrainingMenu, PublicationMenu

class PublicationApp(CMSApp):
    name = _("Publication App") # give your app a name, this is required
    urls = ["resources.pub_urls"] # link your app to url configuration(s)
    menus = [PublicationMenu]

class TrainingApp(CMSApp):
    name = _("Training App") # give your app a name, this is required
    urls = ["resources.train_urls"] # link your app to url configuration(s)
    menus = [TrainingMenu]

apphook_pool.register(PublicationApp) # register your app
apphook_pool.register(TrainingApp) # register your app
```

Is something like this possible? Or do I have to split this into two different apps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing to stop your `urls.py` simply acting as a way of including multiple other urls files:

`urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include   
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + patterns('',
                                         (r'^', include('pub_urls')),
                                         (r'^', include('train_urls')))
```

`pub_urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'homeview'),
    (r'^stuff/$', 'stuffview')
)
```

etc.

`ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings file points to the root url file.

Answer (score 4):

Django doesn't care what your urlpatterns file is called. The default base urlconf is by convention called urls.py, but in fact that's [just a setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#root-urlconf) and can be overridden. After that, you need to explicitly include urlconfs by module name, so again it makes no difference what they're called.

I'm not familiar with Django-CMS and I don't know what it's doing in its CMSApp class, but I suspect you're going to have to dig into that to see what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

It is configurable using `ROOT_URLCONF` setting.

[From django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-ROOT_URLCONF)

```
ROOT_URLCONF 
  A string representing the full Python import path to your root URLconf. 
  For example: "mydjangoapps.urls". Can be overridden on a per-request basis 
  by setting the attribute urlconf on the incoming HttpRequest object. See How 
  Django processes a request for details.
```

You can also write/get a middleware which can set it appropriately depending upon the host or other parameters in the request.